# Let U be uniformly distributed on the interval [-1,1]. Define V=U^2. What is corr(U,V)?

Tags: statistics, correlation

Correlation does not describe curved relationships between variables, so the answer should be 0, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The correlation in this case does happen to be $0$, but there's more to it than that.  There are lots of "curved relationships" that have nonzero correlation. For example, the correlation of $U$ and $U^3$ would be nonzero.

Hint: Express the covariance in terms of expected values, and use symmetry to show some of these are $0$.

Comment: Indeed this is an example where the correlation is $0$. But you would have got a positive correlation if you had started with $U$ uniform on $[0,1]$ and a negative correlation if you had started with $U$ uniform on $[-1,0]$